# What material should I use for the plates of my homemade mica capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, conductivity, dielectric, conductors

I recently acquired some mica as i want to build my own high voltage (50 kV if possible) capacitors. The problem I am encountering right now is that the surface of such a crystal isn't perfectly flat but rather uneven. My plan was to simply use aluminium foil as the conducting plates but it doesn't fill said indentations.

I thought about melting a material directly onto the surface but what is a suitable substance for this task? If possible I would prefere to not buy some special equipment. I have a gas soldering iron whose flame is supposedly 1300°C hot. That should be enough for thin sheets of  metals with a low melting point.



Do you know about a suitable material or possibly another solution?

By the way it should not release any toxic gases as I want to produce the capacitors at home.

Comment: Solder would be an obvious choice with its low melting point and ready availability.

Comment: See [Silver mica capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_mica_capacitor). I believe the silver is deposited using [sputtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sputtering).

Comment: The traditional partner for mica is silver. It may be annealed (in the soft state) and pressed on to the mica if you don't want to melt it. Dave's probably right about sputtering; not something I've tried to do at home.

Comment: I have heard about silver but that would be rather expensive right? I will have to do some research on silver prices @BrianDrummond

Comment: @hanslhansl nah, the amount of silver you'd need would cost negligibly much compared to the rest of your 50 kV setup. Remember, you need nearly nothing: only the very closest few layers of silver contribute to the capacity, and you'll definitely not need much silver to fulfill the current needs. Have you calculated how much capacity you'll **need** by now? I feel like you're really dancing around that one :) Without knowing that, how would you know how much silver you'd need?

Comment: Gold leaf sounds like a good candidate. This can be as thin (and so low cost) as you wish - gold leafcan be rolled out and rolled out and rolled  .... - to the extent that (I'm told) that you can see through it. At that stage (I'm told (again :-) )) it's green. Gold is nicely malleable and could be rubbed/worked into the surface. You can also join pieces of gold leaf together by mechanical rubbing.

Comment: @MarcusMüller This entire thing is just me experimenting. I do not need a specific capacity but the more the better. The surface of the mica I got is around 18 cm^2 big. With the dielectric being 1mm thick and mica having a permittivity of around 5 that results in a capacity of 80 pF. As you said the thickness of the plates doesn't really affect the capacity. Therefor, if I am not mistaken, i need enough silver to cover 2 x 18 cm^2. It really is the size of the crystal and not what I want that dictates the outcome of this experiment.

Comment: then, really, calculate whether what you want to build works with 80 pF +- 30%.

Comment: That really is not a lot of capacitance, and it's hard to measure and experiment with something that is in the regions of stray capacitances of all the rest of your system :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller You are probably right. I am also not sure whether there are any micas which are much bigger than mine. I will have to stick to waxed paper :)

Answer (score 2):

> What material should I use for the plates of my homemade mica capacitors?

Gold leaf sounds like a good candidate.
This can be as thin (and so low cost) as you wish - gold leaf can be rolled out and rolled out and rolled  .... - to the extent that (I'm told) that you can see through it. At that stage (I'm told (again :-) )) it's green.

Gold is nicely malleable and could be rubbed/worked into the surface.
You can also join pieces of gold leaf together by mechanical rubbing.